# c# encapsulation Get/ Set

Tags: c#, properties, get, set, encapsulation

looking for some clarification on **Get / Set**.  I have this code which I use to create my objects..However I want to have *some validation* in with the `length` and `width` (both need to be greater than some number as example).  I believe **Get / Set** is the way to go and I have used this when changing fields in an instance - but how do I do it at the Instantiation stage?

```
class Room
{
    public Double dblLength;
    public Double dblWidth;

    public Room (Double _dblLength, Double _dblWidth)
    {

        dblLength = _dblLength;
        dblWidth = _dblWidth;
    }
```

Comment: First don't make fields public. Make them get-only properties and then do the checking/validation in the constructor and throw `ArgumentException` if the validation doesn't pass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn *fields* into *properties*; implement validation within corresponding `set`:

```
class Room
{
    private Double m_DblLength;
    private Double m_DblWidth;

    public Room (Double _dblLength, Double _dblWidth) {
      DblLength = _dblLength;
      DblWidth = _dblWidth;
    }

    public Double DblLength {
      get {
        return m_DblLength;
      }
      set {
        //TODO: validation here
        if (value < 0)
          throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value"); 

        m_DblLength = value;
      }
    }

    public Double DblWidth {
      get {
        return m_DblWidth;
      }
      set {
        //TODO: validation here
        if (value < 0)
          throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value"); 

        m_DblWidth = value;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your class is immutable, the easiest is:

```
class Room
{
    public double Length { get; }
    public double Width { get; }

    public Room(double length, double width)
    {
        // Validation here, for instance throw exception if length <= 0
        Length = length;
        Width = width;
    }
}
```

Using [C# 6's readonly auto properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#read-only-auto-properties).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example, based on Alex's comment. Personally I'd also get rid of the underscores and 'dbl' prefix, but I've left them in to match the question.

You can't return a failure message from a constructor, so throw an exception.

```
class Room
  {
  private Double dblLength;
  private Double dblWidth;

  public Room (Double _dblLength, Double _dblWidth)
  {
    if (_dblLength < _dblWidth)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("length must be more than width");
    }

    dblLength = _dblLength;
    dblWidth = _dblWidth;
  }
}
```

This is appropriate if it indicates that the programmer using your class doesn't understand it. However if there is a good chance of this happening at run time, you might be better to have a 'hasError' flag in the object that prevents it from being saved, or doing whatever it does.

```
  class Room
  {
    private Double dblLength;
    private Double dblWidth;

    public bool HasError {get;}

    public Room (Double _dblLength, Double _dblWidth)
    {
      if (_dblLength < _dblWidth)
      {
          HasError = true;
      }

      dblLength = _dblLength;
      dblWidth = _dblWidth;
    }

    public Save()
    {
        if (HasError) return;
        // Otherwise do the save;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the fields into [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties). When you have changed the fields into properties you can then validate the `value` which will be set to the according property and if it does not meet the requirements you can throw an exception.

Example:

```
class Room
    {
        private double _dblLength;
        private double _dblWidth;

        public double DblLength {
            get
            {
                return _dblLength;
            }
            set
            {
                //TODO -> Do validation
                //the keyword value represents the value that you want to pass to the property
                if(value < 0)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("message");
                }

                _dblLength = value;
            }
        }
        public double DblWidth
        {
            get
            {
                return _dblWidth;
            }
            set
            {
                //TODO -> Do validation
                //the keyword value represents the value that you want to pass to the property
                if (value < 1)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("message");
                }

                _dblWidth = value;
            }
        }

        public Room(Double _dblLength, Double _dblWidth)
        {
            DblLength = _dblLength;
            DblWidth = _dblWidth;
        }
    }
```

Another good thing to do is if you want the properties to be set only when an instance is created(only through the constructor) you can make the setter `private` like so:

```
class Room
    {
        private double _dblLength;
        private double _dblWidth;

        public double DblLength {
            get
            {
                return _dblLength;
            }
            private set
            {
                //TODO -> Do validation
                //the keyword value represents the value that you want to pass to the property
                if(value < 0)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("message");
                }

                _dblLength = value;
            }
        }
        public double DblWidth
        {
            get
            {
                return _dblWidth;
            }
            private set
            {
                //TODO -> Do validation
                //the keyword value represents the value that you want to pass to the property
                if (value < 1)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("message");
                }

                _dblWidth = value;
            }
        }

        public Room(Double _dblLength, Double _dblWidth)
        {
            DblLength = _dblLength;
            DblWidth = _dblWidth;
        }
    }
```

This is possible because properties are just syntax sugar provided to us by C#. When this code is compiled the compiler will create two methods `Get` and `Set` for each property. Thus if you put an access modifier on the getter or setter the compiler will take that in mind and when it compiles the code, it will put the modifier which you have specified. However, if no specific modifier is specified the compiler will take the modifier of the property itself in the above case the `Get` method will be public and the `Set` method will be private. After compilation the code will look something like this:

```
class Room
{
    private double _dblLength;
    private double _dblWidth;

    public Room(Double _dblLength, Double _dblWidth)
    {
        SetDblLength(_dblLength);
        SetDblWidth(_dblWidth);
    }

    public double GetDblLength()
    {
        return _dblLength;
    }

    private void SetDblLength(double value)
    {
        if (value < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("message");
        }

        _dblLength = value;
    }

    public double GetDblWidth()
    {
        return _dblWidth;
    }

    private void SetDblWidth(double value)
    {
        if (value < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("message");
        }

        _dblWidth = value;
    }
}
```